# why sizeof("-2147483648") - 1

Tags: c, macros, precompile

When reading nginx source code, I find this line:

```
#define NGX_INT32_LEN   sizeof("-2147483648") - 1
```

why using sizeof("-2147483648") - 1?

not sizeof(-2147483648) - 1

not -2147483648 - 1

not -2147483649 
or else?

What's the difference?

Comment: `sizeof("1234")` definitely isn't the same as `sizeof(1234)`, which definitely isn't the same as `1234`. The first is the size of a character array, the second is the size of an integer, and the third is the plain value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically -2147483648 is the *widest*, in terms of characters required for its representation, of any of the signed 32-bit integers.  This macro `NGX_INT32_LEN` defines how many characters long such an integer can be.

It does this by taking the amount of space needed for that string constant, and subtracting 1 (because `sizeof` will provided space for the trailing NUL character).  It's quicker than using:

```
strlen("-2147483648")
```

because not all compilers will translate that into the constant `11`.